# Image upload resulting in empty $_FILES array in magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, image, save

In my custom module I'm trying to upload an image via my save controller, I added the form in my block with this code:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model  = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('homepagecontent_blocks');
    $form   = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('content_');
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('content');


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('General')]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'image',
        array(
            'name' => 'image',
            'label' => __('Image'),
            'title' => __('Image')
        )
    );
```

When I var_dump my $_POST value, this is displayed:

```
array (size=3)
'form_key' => string 'ri7aWhZX3L56e10f' (length=16)
'content' => 
array (size=7)
  'css_grid_column_from' => string '1' (length=1)
  'css_grid_column_to' => string '2' (length=1)
  'css_grid_row_from' => string '4' (length=1)
  'css_grid_row_to' => string '1' (length=1)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'link' => string 'asfasf' (length=6)
  'text' => string 'hdghgf' (length=6)
'image' => string 'imagename.jpeg' (length=15)
```

However my $_FILES variable is empty. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `multipart/form-data enctype` in your form in order to process image file, try to replace this code :

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create();
```

with this one :

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(
[
'data' => [
           'id' => 'id_form',
           'method' => 'post',
           'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
          ]
       ]
);
```

hope this help

Comment: glad to hear that, please mark this answer as acceptance answer to help others which have same case in the future :)